# Arduino Uno stops executing after about 88 loops

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a weather station i used DHT11 and BMP180 and GSM Sim808 module that sent every 5 min a text message. the problem after 88 sending void loop() function Stoped. What can be the reason for this stop, after two successful loops?
Below is my code:

```
//Sim808//d
#include <DFRobot_sim808.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define PHONE_NUMBER "0660121981"
#define PHONE_NUMBER2 "0660121983"
#define MESSAGE  "karim"
#define PIN_TX    10
#define PIN_RX    11
SoftwareSerial mySerial(PIN_TX, PIN_RX);
DFRobot_SIM808 sim808(&mySerial);
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Time.h>
//BMP180//
#include <SFE_BMP180.h>
SFE_BMP180 bmp180;
float comp;
int Altitude = 11; //current altitude in meters
//DHT11//
#include "DHT.h"
#define DHTPIN 5     // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
//SDL Weather//
#include "SDL_Weather_80422.h"
#define pinLED     13   // LED connected to digital pin 13
#define pinAnem    3  // Anenometer connected to pin 18 - Int 5 - Mega   / Uno pin 2
#define pinRain    5  // Anenometer connected to pin 2 - Int 0 - Mega   / Uno Pin 3 
#define intAnem    1  // int 0 (check for Uno)
#define intRain    0  // int 1
SDL_Weather_80422 weatherStation(pinAnem, pinRain, intAnem, intRain, A1, SDL_MODE_INTERNAL_AD);
//Declaration//
uint8_t i;
float currentWindSpeed;
float currentWindGust;
float totalRain;
int sending =1;
int counting=0;
void setup()
{

  //Begin//
  Serial.begin(57600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  bool success = bmp180.begin();
  //PIN//
  pinMode(7, INPUT);           // set pin to input
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
  ////
  Serial.println("-----------");
  Serial.println("WeatherArduino SDL_Weather_80422 Class Test");
  Serial.println("Version 1.1");
  Serial.println("-----------");


  weatherStation.setWindMode(SDL_MODE_SAMPLE, 5.0);
  //weatherStation.setWindMode(SDL_MODE_DELAY, 5.0);
  totalRain = 0.0;
  //******** Initialize sim808 module *************
  while (!sim808.init()) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("Sim808 init error\r\n");
  }
  Serial.println("Sim808 init success");

  //******** define phone number and text **********

  sim808.sendSMS(PHONE_NUMBER, "Bienvenue sur Safetrack Station Meteo");
  //sim808.callUp(PHONE_NUMBER);
}
void loop()
{
 if(counting>=2){
  counting=0;
  delay(1000);
  asm volatile ( "jmp 0");
 }
  currentWindSpeed = weatherStation.current_wind_speed() / 1.6;
  currentWindGust = weatherStation.get_wind_gust() / 1.6;
  totalRain = totalRain + weatherStation.get_current_rain_total() / 25.4;
  //DHT11//
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  //BMP180//
  char status;
  double T, P;
  bool success = false;
  status = bmp180.startTemperature();

  if (status != 0) {
    delay(1000);
    status = bmp180.getTemperature(T);

    if (status != 0) {
      status = bmp180.startPressure(3);

      if (status != 0) {
        delay(status);
        status = bmp180.getPressure(P, T);

        if (status != 0) {
          comp = bmp180.sealevel(P, Altitude);

        }
      }
    }
  }
  //Serial//
  String str = "Vitesse vent:" + String(currentWindSpeed*1.60934,2)+"KPH\r\n"+"Direction:"+String(weatherStation.current_wind_direction())+" Degre\r\n"+"Humidite:"+String(h)+" %\r\n"+"Temperature:"+String(t)+" C\r\n"+"Pression:"+String(comp)+"hPa\r\n"+"Pluie:"+String("0.00 mm");
  char copy[150];
  str.toCharArray(copy, 150);
  sim808.sendSMS(PHONE_NUMBER, copy);
  sim808.sendSMS(PHONE_NUMBER2, copy);
counting++;
delay(300000);
}
```

I have a weather station i used DHT11 and BMP180 and GSM Sim808 module that sent every 5 min a text message. the problem after 88 sending void loop() function Stoped. What can be the reason for this stop, after two successful loops?

Comment: don't use String class

Comment: I will change it with what

Comment: C strings https://majenko.co.uk/blog/evils-arduino-strings

Comment: thanks you bro for your help

Comment: After two loops that bit at the beginning of the loop will run.  The part with the jmp 0.  What is that there for?  That's why it stops at two loops.

Comment: It's only a solution I do reboot arduino but until it does not work the arduino stops after a while